# How do I calculate a cosinor analysis in SPSS, HELP!

Tags: syntax, trigonometry, spss

How can I put this into spss???

http://www.cbi.dongnocchi.it/glossary/Cosinor.html

I am trying to calculate the MESOR for a cyclic pattern of circadian rhythm.

Answer (score 1):

SPSS is not very good about including built-in procedures for anything beyond very standard social science statistics. However, what you want to do (or something like it, I'm not familiar with the method) is apparently feasible if you transform your variables and then run a linear regression, as documented [here](http://www.spssusers.co.uk/Events/1997/cosinor.ppt) (a powerpoint file).

If it isn't strictly necessary to use SPSS, you're probably better off using something like R where what you want is more likely to be formally implemented. Check out the [season package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/season/season.pdf).